# Internal microphone not working on a Compaq Presario CQ60

Tags: 11.10, microphone, compaq, presario

the internal microphone of my COMPAQ Presario CQ60 is not working.
i notice it when calling on skype i could not be understood.
i checked if skype was disabling my microphone due to its auto regulator, but that wasn't the problem.
i controlled the audio option and when i notice that the microphone does not detect any sound

in the previous version of ubuntu i did not have any issue with the microphone.

can you help me? let me know if you need any particular information
thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your internal microphone is detected by Ubuntu 11.10, so I think you can try some of the solutions proposed in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77888/microphone-problem-in-ubuntu-11-10). If you still have problems, then file a bug in Launchpad following this [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Ubuntu is trying to pick up a different input device (i.e. the input jack for the mic instead of the internal mic). Try to open the sound settings (speaker icon in the upper right corner of the screen), and under the **Input** tab, choose a different **connector**, and see if any sound is detected. Try to move the slider too to adjust the volume, so that it isn't too low or too high.

Comment: try playing with audio option but nothing. On hardware i chose "Duplex stereo analogico" (italian ubuntu) and on the input tap i tryied both analogic  an internal microphone but nothing; there is only one device choice under that i can choose