# How to make my microphone unmuted on startup?

Tags: sound, startup, microphone, google-talk, mute

Every time I boot the microphone is muted. I want it to be unmuted instead.
Of course I can do it by 6 easy steps every time:

1. press sound icon in the upper right of the screen.
2. press "Sound settings..." item in the bottom.
3. wait about 10 seconds until a window loads.
4. switch to input tab.
5. uncheck "Mute" checkbox near a microphone icon.
6. close the window.

But I want it to be unmuted by default.

I guess that in linux world this should be changing 0 to 1 in some line in some configuration file, but I don't really know, where is this line located.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77888/microphone-problem-in-ubuntu-11-10) previous answer:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and add or change the following:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto enable=yes
```

BTW, if you prefer to use the gnome editor rather than text editing in the terminal, you could also run `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. As far as I know, it is still better to run gksudo rather than sudo to start gnome/kde/unity applications with a GUI in super-user-mode.