# How to mute volume on every boot in Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: boot, kubuntu, mute

I want to set the speaker and microphone volume to zero or mute them every time my laptop starts, even if the last time I shut down my computer they where not muted. Just like what Kali Linux does.
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

This answer from stack exchange should do the trick: [Set Ubuntu Sound Volume on boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414894/set-ubuntu-sound-volume-on-boot)

From the question you want to use this command:

```
`/usr/bin/amixer -c 0 sset Master,0 0% > /dev/null`
```

From the answer you want to add the command in:

```
/etc/rc.local
```

Insert the command after the first line and before the last line:

```
#!/bin/sh    # <---- This is the first line

`/usr/bin/amixer -c 0 sset Master,0 0% > /dev/null`

exit 0       # <---- This is the last line
```

---

In my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS sound is already muted on boot. This happens to others as well: [How to make my microphone unmuted on startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162153/how-to-make-my-microphone-unmuted-on-startup)

Check the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and look for the line:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto enable=yes
```

If it exists either delete it or put `#` in the first character position.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, but what about the microphone? I tried to look at the man pages with no luck.

Comment: I've added option for microphone but as it is already muted on my system cannot verify if it would work for you.